# C++ program compiler run the exe file automatically after compiling with g++ command

Tags: c++, g++, mingw

For running C++ program we first run "g++ file.cpp" and then we run "a.exe" in CMD
Can we do it all in single command? If yes, how?

Comment: Depending on your environment you could write a bash script that does this for you. Or just type something like `g++ file.cpp && ./a.exe`

Comment: I m not familiar with bash, yet can you show an example how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `&&`:

```
g++ file.cpp && a.exe
```

Comment: It should be `./a.exe`

Comment: @A.K. For me CMD runs executables even without the `./`.

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 options:

1. g++ file.cpp && ./a.exe
2. g++ file.cpp ; ./a.exe

a) The first one execute your program (a.exe) even if the compilation failed (if you have already compiled your program previously of course).

b) The second do not run your program if the compilation failed (even if you have already compiled your program previously).

So the 2nd option is more correct because you are sure that if the compilation failed you wouldn't run your previously executable.